# Deploy SkiaSharp on a container running .NET 6 Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, docker, .net-6.0, alpine-linux, skiasharp

SkiaSharp fails at runtime when deployed to an alpine linux container, using .NET 6.0 with the following error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo' threw an exception.
> ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libSkiaSharp' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibSkiaSharp: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> at SkiaSharp.SkiaApi.sk_colortype_get_default_8888()
> at SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo..cctor()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at ZXing.SkiaSharp.Rendering.SKBitmapRenderer.Render(BitMatrix matrix, BarcodeFormat format, String content, EncodingOptions options)
> at ZXing.BarcodeWriter`1.Write(String contents)

I have tried (with no effect)

- Adding a reference to `SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux`
- Swapping with a reference to `SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDepedencies`
- Swapping with a reference to `StoneCold.SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.AlpineLinux`
- Rolling back version from 2.88.3 to 2.80.3
- Copying libSkiaSharp.so /usr/lib/
- Adding my publish directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Project file

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp" Version="2.80.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux" Version="2.80.3" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
```

My current Dockerfile (simplified)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Web"
RUN dotnet build "Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish -r alpine-x64 --no-self-contained

FROM base AS final
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libfontconfig1 fontconfig \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/app/publish/
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY --from=publish /app/publish/libSkiaSharp.so /usr/lib/
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000 
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update: Working Solution** Thanks @omajid

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-alpine AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Web"
RUN dotnet build "Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish -r linux-musl-x64 --no-self-contained

FROM base AS final
RUN apk update \
    && apk --no-cache add icu-libs fontconfig ttf-dejavu
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000 
ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Web.dll"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are targeting your application for alpine, but you are running it in the `final` container, which is based on `base`:

```
FROM base AS final
```

And `base` is just

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
```

And that's a Debian 11 image:

```
$ podman run -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 /bin/bash
root@61566364141c:/# cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

So, you probably want to switch the base container to alpine before running it? Alternatively, target `linux-x64` instead of `alpine-x64`?

Also, Microsoft's recommendation is to use generic RIDs (eg, `linux-musl-x64`, or `linux-arm64`) instead of specific ones (eg `alpine-x64` or `rhel.8-arm64`).

Comment: Great pick-up thank you! I'm suprised i have not encountered any issues with this set-up previously.

Answer (score 0):

For .net 8.0, I figured out my issue from this question itself and https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4775 . Here is my solution

1. Need to update Dockerfile
2. Need to install `SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux` OR `SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies` into your project. Either one works. ***Without this you will have exception (in Linux)***

My simplified Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src


...
...
...


FROM base AS final
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libfontconfig
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

Notice `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfontconfig` **is the fix**